# Console widget wxpython

Tags: windows, linux, wxpython, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I have forked an interpreter written in C ([Picoc](http://code.google.com/p/picoc/)), and I want to create a GUI for that interpreter.

The GUI should have a textarea (TextView in pygtk) and a console in the bottom, that will show the output of the script that you just written, and also prompt the input if its needed.

I do create a **PyGTK** GUI that has **VTE Console widget**, but the problem is that i want to make **PyGTK cross-platform**, i'm using GTKSourceView and as i was looking on Google, its no so easy to port GTK to windows, so, i research about WxPython (which is the same window Manager of Code::Blocks), but the question is:

It DO exists a Console Widget on wxPython?

and most important, how portable it is? can i port it to windows easier than GTK?

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that PyGTK is cross-platform. It just doesn't use native widgets. I've certainly used an application written in it on Windows anyway. Admittedly, I've never had much luck actually using it on Windows.

As for wxPython, no it doesn't have a console widget. You would have to use Python's subprocess to launch a console window and communicate with it. On the other hand, wxPython is quite portable. I've seen screenshots of apps on all 3 major platforms and I've written a couple of mine to work on Windows and Ubuntu.